# Apollo Client + NextJs Authentication problem

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, next.js

I am developing an intranet application with React (NextJs) and Apollo Client. I need restrict all page. I want to redirect unauthenticated user to login page, but in the Query I get the following error:

`Error: No router instance found. You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.`

The Query is working, the only problem is related to Router. Why i can't access to it from Query and how to solve it?

```
 return (
    <>
      <Meta/>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <CssBaseline/>
        <Header/>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <Query query={CURRENT_USER_QUERY}>
            {({ data: { me } }) => {
              if(!me) {
                const { pathname } = this.props.router;
                if (pathname !== '/login') {
                  Router.push('/login');
                  return null;
                }
              }

              if (me) return (
                  <>
                    <div className={classes.toolbar}/>
                    {this.props.children}
                  </>
              );

              return <Login/>;
            }}
          </Query>
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
);
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Does the `Router` work elsewhere? Do you have this error only in this component?

Comment: Yes, it's working. This error appear when I try to use Router in Query.

Comment: @eldavidthe problem is because with nextJS, the query can be executed on the client side and on the server side. You can follow this example of handling authentication with apollo and nextJS: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo-auth Specially the lib/Redirect file